# How to print token in webform-confirmation.html.twig?

Tags: theming, webforms, tokens

I would like to output a submitted value as a token on the confirmation page through the twig. The token works just fine when added into the message box of webform as:

```
[webform_submission:values:score_percentage]
```

But I can't seem to get the same value to output through the twig. I have tried:

```
{{ webform_token('webform_submission:values:score_percentage') }}
{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:score_percentage]') }}
{{ drupal_token('webform_submission:values:score_percentage') }}
{{ drupal_token('[webform_submission:values:score_percentage]') }}
```

But they all just print the token itself, like:

```
webform_submission:values:score_percentage
[webform_submission:values:score_percentage]
[webform_submission:values:score_percentage]
[[webform_submission:values:score_percentage]]
```

[I saw another post about (what I think is) the same thing here? But I haven't been able to see my error...](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/290347/how-can-i-access-webform-submission-values-from-webform-confirmation-html-twig)

As well as [this old issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2845318), which by the looks of it would be fixed now.

I have the latest versions of Twig Tweak (8.x-2.9) and Token (8.x-1.9) installed. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the code that implements `webform_token`, you can check the *src/Twig/WebformTwigExtension.php* file, line 102.

```php
public function webformToken($token, EntityInterface $entity = NULL....) {
  // Allow the webform_token function to be tested during validation without
  // a valid entity.
  if (!$entity) {
    return $token;
  }
  // …
}
```

If you do not pass an entity, the string passed in, for example, `{{ webform_token('webform_submission:values:score_percentage') }}` will be returned.

If you look at the *templates/webform-confirmation.html.twig* file, you can see the following variables are available.

- progress: Progress bar
- message: Confirmation message
- back_url: URL to the previous webform submission

The other available variables can be found on `template_preprocess_webform_confirmation()`.

- webform
- webform_submission
- source_entity

It means you can use `{{ webform_submission.data.field_name }}` in the *webform-confirmation.html.twig* file, instead of using tokens as you did.

Try to avoid using Twig extensions in template files. It will make debugging and maintenance easier.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module and use `{{ drupal_token('site:name') }}`.